# Flash videos and DVD format

Tags: flash

How can I convert a Flash (youtube video) to DVD format getting the video burned in a DVD?

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG ( http://www.ffmpeg.org/ ) will convert pretty much anything into pretty much anything else - and it comes with a handy command-line interface!

Answer (score 1):

[DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/) can automatically convert your videos to DVD format and record them on a DVD disc. DVD Flick supports Flash Video format and it's freeware.

> DVD Flick can take a number of video
>   files stored on your computer and turn
>   them into a DVD that will play back on
>   your DVD player, Media Center or Home
>   Cinema Set. You can add additional
>   custom audio tracks, subtitles as well
>   as a menu for easier navigation.
>
> Features:
>
> - Burn near any video file to DVD
> - Support for over 45 file formats
> - Support for over 60 video codecs
> - Support for over 40 audio codecs
> - Easily add a menu
> - Add your own subtitles
> - Easy to use interface
> - Burn your project to disc after encoding
> - Completely free without any adware, spyware or limitations